# What is "parent element" of ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

`R`, `ggplot2` question.

`?ggplot2::rel()` says

> rel() is used to specify sizes relative to the parent.

What is the "parent" exactly? For example, I'd love to set the size of my plot title to `rel(5)`. What is the width of my title in inches exactly?

I noticed there are two "units" that I believe somehow are used as a relevant size in ggplot2, `.pt`. I think there is some relation between `rel()` and `.pt`. `.pt` equals to `2.845276`. Why?? And 2.845276 of what? Pixels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parents are defined in `help("theme")`. Note how for most arguments the documentation says "inherits from ...". This is object oriented programming.

E.g., `axis.text` is the parent of `axis.text.x`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
DF <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 2)
p1 <- ggplot(DF, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
p2 <- p1 + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = rel(2)))
p3 <- p2 + theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 5))

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, ncol = 1)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: what is the default size of `axis.text`? 11?  And do you know how to calculate size in inches from the `size` for a given plot?

Comment: Look at the output of `theme_grey` to find out the defaults. `axis.text` is 0.8 * `text` size and `text` size equals `base_size` with a default of 11 pts.

Answer (score 1):

The parent element is the graph itself as drawn by the current theme. You can use `rel()`to scale anything relative to the parent object which is not a part of the data (titles, axes and such).

It is specifically used to scale things relative to the rest of the theme for the current plot.

As you might expect with rel being short for relative, there is no absolute size for it, not inches or centimeters. But you can use it to scale your plot's title as follows:

```
g + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(5)))
```

Where g is the plot you are adding things onto.

This tells ggplot to scale the text in your plot title to scale it up 5 relative to rest of the theme. You can also scale it down using decimals. The numbers are a bit weird, like with line sizes or glyph sizes, the best thing is to try a few to see what gets you closest to where you want to be!

Comment: I expected an answer talking about `.pt` and `.strock`. There is an parameter `base_size = 11` inside themes, e.g. `theme_gray()`. I am guessing that the `rel()` is related to the `base_size`, which is further related to the `.pt`.

Comment: Yes, it is relative to the base size! But you can use it on every single object in a theme to highly customize the sizes relative to the base in a limitless manner.

Comment: "The parent element is the graph itself as drawn by the current theme." - This seems a bit off to me. The ggplot theme system has a very clear hierarchy/inheritance system, so `plot.title` inherits from `title` which inherits from `text`. Those are the parent elements being referred to.

Comment: It was a weak explanation on my part. But you can change any of themes objects relative to  to the current themes sizing. And it can be applied to many parts of the theme.

Answer (score 1):

with regards `2.845276`,

```
all.equal(convertUnit(unit(1,"mm"),"pt", valueOnly = TRUE), ggplot2::.pt)
```